# Updating form component in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf

I have an ajax call that updates a value on my dto and should update the form to stop rendering a certain component. When mode of trial is changed, it should update a java value (which is working correctly and also stop the rendering on the time limit field.

If update="@form" is set, the rendering works correctly however all values are cleared from the form as well which is not acceptable. If I try to target the update at the id of the field, it doesn't work, I assume this has something to do with the repeat. The id of the component when inspecting the web page is 'offencesForm:offences:0:statutoryTimeLimit' however updating that does not work either.

Any help updating the rendering of the component without clearing the values of the rest of the form, would be great.

The dropdown that is change to trigger the method which is hit.

```
<ui:repeat id="offences" value="#{casefileDto.offences}" var="_offence" varStatus="n">

    <!-- Update Time Limit value in dto & update component to render statutoryTimeLimit by modeOfTrial value -->
    <ecis:field label="Mode of trial" starred="true" help="#{label['casefile.help.modeOfTrial']}" helpLayout="hover">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{_offence.modeOfTrial}" 
                        converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter"
                        required="${param['skipValidation'] == null}" requiredMessage="Please select the mode of trial">
            <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{conditionCache.modeOfTrialConditions}" />
            <p:ajax event="change" update="statutoryTimeLimit" listener="#{_offence.onTrialModeSelect()}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </ecis:field>

    <!-- Render based off modeOfTrial values -->
    <ecis:field id="statutoryTimeLimit" label="Statutory time limit expires on" rendered="#{supplementary and _offence.timeLimitRequired()}"
                help="Calculated from 'Date of offence' plus six months." helpLayout="hover">
        <h:outputText value="#{_offence.statutoryTimeLimit}" >
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{cvCache.dateFormat}" />
        </h:outputText>
    </ecis:field>

</ui:repeat>
```

Java code

```
public boolean timeLimitRequired() {
    return modeOfTrial != null && modeOfTrial.getValue().contains("(SST)");
}

public void onTrialModeSelect() {
    if (getModeOfTrial().toString().equals("Not suitable for summary trial (NSST)")) {
        setStatutoryTimeLimit(null);
    } else {
        onOffenceDateSelect();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried chaning the update from @ form to update=":offences"? This should only reload the element with id="offences"

Comment: Your problem suggests that `<ecis:field>` is actually a `NamingContainer` component. Is this true? Note that composite components by default implement `NamingContainer` but normal components or tagfiles not.